# Leitura de csv com django

Tags: banco-de-dados, python, django, csv

Bom, estou trabalhando com uma base de dados aberta, e ela está em CSV, estou utilizando DJANGO para fazer a leitura do CSV e assim inserindo no banco de dados...Porém está dando um falha na inserção do primeiro ano,estou tentando inserir 8 anos de dados, o primeiro ano ele insere somente 11 meses, assim fica faltando inserir 1 mês para fechar corretamente os dados.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from models import Internacao
import csv


def csvInternacao(request):
        coluna = 1
        mes = 1
        ano = 2008
        while (ano < 2017):
            with open('locale', 'rb') as csvfile:
                spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
                for row in spamreader:
                    if row[0] is not None:
                        t = Internacao()
                        t.idmunicipios = row[0]
                        t.quantidade = row[coluna]
                        t.data = str(ano) + '-' + str(mes) + '-01'
                        t.save(force_insert=True)
                        print t.idmunicipios, t.data, t.quantidade
            mes = mes + 1
            coluna = coluna + 1
            print mes
            if coluna%12 == 0:
                print ano
                mes = 1
                ano = ano + 1
```

Assim fazendo a leitura de cada coluna do csv e alterando as colunas automaticamente e alterando o ano, pois cada coluna é um mês. Alguém sabe por que não estou conseguindo fazer a inserção corretamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se suas colunas estão baseadas em `1`, então seu menor valor [válido] será `1` e seu maior valor será `12`. Isso significa que você só deve resetar o mês quando o valor não se tornar mais válido - ou seja, `13`.

Na segunda iteração, a coluna iniciará com `12 + 1 = 13` e terminará com `12 + 12 = 24`, de modo que você resetará quando chegar em `12 + 13 = 25`. Etc. Ou seja, não é quando `coluna%12` for zero que você tem que resetar, e sim no índice seguinte a ele:

```
if (coluna-1)%12 == 0:
    print ano
    mes = 1
    ano = ano + 1
```

Alternativamente, você pode fazer o teste antes de atualizar `coluna`, e não depois:

```
if coluna%12 == 0:
    print ano
    mes = 1
    ano = ano + 1
else:
    mes = mes + 1
    print mes

coluna = coluna + 1
```

O resultado será o mesmo (exceto pelo `print`, que imagino estar aí só pra depuração, certo?). Pessoalmente, acho que na segunda forma a lógica fica mais clara.

Comment: Resolvido amigo, da segunda maneira funcionou também...Resolvi também fazendo  `if coluna%12 == 1:
                print ano
                mes = 1
                ano = ano + 1`
Esse print é só para depurar mesmo...mas funcionou 100%!! Obrigado!

Comment: @MarceloHenriqueCasali se a resposta realmente ajudou/resolveu deve aceita-la, em baixo da seta para baixo à esquerda da resposta